# How do I dynamically name an instance or change the attributes of all instances in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to model population growth using individual agents, but have already run into trouble with the basic skeleton of the model.

I have a class to hold individuals

```
class Individual:
    """These are individuals"""
    list = []
    def __init__(self, name, sex, dob):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
        self.dob = dob
        self.list.append(name)
    def __str__(self):
        return "name is {}, sex is {}, age is {}" .format(self.name, self.sex, curyear - self.dob)
```

and I instantiate new individuals through

```
def birth():
    global person
    person = Individual((next(name)), randsex(), curyear)
```

The basic growth loop is

```
for i in range(totalyears):
    curyear = curyear + 1
    if curyear - person.dob == 18:
        birth()
    else:
        pass
```

The problem seems to be that

```
if curyear - person.dob == 18:
    birth()
```

is only ageing and checking the last instance of `Individual` that's created.

`print (Individual.list)` shows that my final population = starting population + total years /18 and `print (str(person))` too seems to confirm this.

I think this is because my `birth()` function basically names each new instance 'person', so whenever I use `person.whatever` it references the latest instance created. It seems to me that there are two possibilities.

A) Dynamically give each new instance a unique name, and use a list to reference each of these instances' attributes in the growth loop.

B) Add an age instance attribute and figure out how to change this for all members of the class.

I don't know if either is possible, or how to do them. I would appreciate any advice and examples!

Comment: Yes, whenever you're instantiating many things that you need to individually address, use a list! Also, `else: pass` is nonsense, it doesn't do anything, you may as well leave it out entirely.

Comment: You have just **one** global `person`. `person` is not a list, it's a single reference. Why not use a `persons` list and append to it instead?

Comment: You need to keep your objects in a *container* like a `list`. Don't dynamically create a bunch of variables.